# Binance API + Delphi. Как создать ордер? Ошибка: -1102

Tags: delphi, post, rest, timestamp, indy

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку в создании ордера на фьючерсном рынке Binance.
Причем на спотовом рынке работает (ордер создается), а на фьючерсном выдает ошибку:

> ```
> code:-1102, msg: Mandatory parameter "timestamp" was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed.
> ```

Голову сломал, не понимаю что надо сделать.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  PublicKey='***';
  SecretKey='***';
var
  sign,queryString,requestBody,strOrder,url: String;
  strQuantity,strPrice,strLocalDT: String;
  PostData: TStringStream;
  ST: SystemTime;
  DT: TDateTime;
  idHTTP_Order: TidHTTP;
  ioSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  try
    try
      idHTTP_Order:=TidHTTP.Create(Self);
      idHTTP_Order.HandleRedirects:=True;
      idHTTP_Order.HTTPOptions:=[hoKeepOrigProtocol,hoForceEncodeParams,
                                hoNoProtocolErrorException,hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
      ioSSL:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Self);
      idHTTP_Order.IOHandler:=ioSSL;
      idHTTP_Order.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('X-MBX-APIKEY:'+PublicKey);
      strQuantity:='5.00000';
      strPrice:='2.18380';
      GetSystemTime(ST);
      DT:=EncodeDate(ST.wYear,ST.wMonth,ST.wDay)+
          EncodeTime(ST.wHour,ST.wMinute,ST.wSecond,ST.wMilliseconds);
      strLocalDT:=IntToStr(MilliSecondsBetween(DT,UnixDateDelta));
      queryString:='symbol=ADAUSDT&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC';
      requestBody:='quantity='+strQuantity+'&price='+strPrice+'&recvWindow=5000&timestamp='+strLocalDT;
      sign:=THashSHA2.GetHMAC(RawByteString(queryString+requestBody),SecretKey,SHA256);
      PostData:=TStringStream.Create(requestBody+'&signature='+sign);
      //на споте работает, ордер создается
      //url:='https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?symbol=ADAUSDT&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC';
      //на фьюче не работает, ошибка -1102
      url:='https://fapi.binance.com/fapi/v1/order?symbol=ADAUSDT&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC';
      strOrder:=idHTTP_Order.Post(url,PostData);
    finally
      PostData.DisposeOf;
      ioSSL.DisposeOf;
      idHTTP_Order.DisposeOf;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do ShowMessage('Error Message: '+E.Message);
  end;
  memo2.Lines.Add(strOrder);
end;
```

Comment: Пробовал к strLocalDT добавлять 1000? (в каких-то случаях они хотят на 1000 время побольше)

Comment: Да, конечно. С самим timestamp никаких проблем нет, в этом я уверен. Я делал вплоть до того, что получал их время с сервера, вычислял дельту со своим компом и запросы отправлял с учетом дельты. То есть разница по времени (конечно же по UTC) мне не страшна. Баланс обоих кошельков получаю без проблем, ордера на споте без проблем, а вот фьючерс не хочет. Тут мне кажется дело в передаче параметров методу Post. В этом я не силен, поэтому сообразить не могу как по другому загнать параметры в Post

Comment: логика Binance: `if (timestamp < (serverTime + 1000) && (serverTime - timestamp) <= recvWindow){
    // process request
  } 
  else {
    // reject request
  }` Я в нее вписываюсь)

Comment: Константин, Вы разобрались с ордерами на фьючерсах?
Хотелось бы немного Вашей помощи. По созданию ордера, надо было просто скорректировать URL и сделать его таким же как и для Спота.